# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code:1, address:0x70) in swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, swift2

I get the following error Thread 1:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code:1, address:0x70) in AppDelegate.

I'm using CoreData in my application but when I remove coreData then it runs fine for me. But, **after adding CoreData my app gets crash**.

when I run the app then this message gets in debug Area:

> Failed to call designated initializer on `NSManagedObject` class     'IndustryInsights.IICategoryDAO'

and when app crash then it prints only `(lldb)`

So please help me to fix this problem.

Here is my NSManagedObject class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class IICategoryDAO: NSManagedObject{

    lazy var coreDataStore: IICoreDataStore = {
        let coreDataStore = IICoreDataStore()
        return coreDataStore
    }()

    lazy var coreDataHelper: IICoreDataHelper = {
        let coreDataHelper = IICoreDataHelper()
        return coreDataHelper
    }()

func insertCategory()
{
    print(" ======== Insert ======== ")

        let newItem: IICategoryModel = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataHelper.backgroundContext!) as! IICategoryModel

        newItem.categoryName = "Category-Name"
        newItem.subCategoryName = "Sub-category"

        NSLog("Inserted New Category ")

    self.coreDataHelper.saveContext(self.coreDataHelper.backgroundContext!)

}

// fetch Category
func fetchcategory() -> [IICategoryModel]
{
    NSLog(" ======== Fetch ======== ")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Category")

    var result = [IICategoryModel]()
    do {
        result = try self.coreDataHelper.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [IICategoryModel]

    } catch let nserror1 as NSError{
        error = nserror1
        print("\(error)")

    }

    return result
}

 func deleteCategory()
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Category")
    var result = [IICategoryModel]()
    do {
        result = try self.coreDataHelper.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [IICategoryModel]
    } catch let nserror1 as NSError
    {
                    print("\(nserror1)")
    }
    if result.isEmpty {
        NSLog("Deleted All Families")
    }
    else{
        for resultItem in result {
            let categoryItem = resultItem 
            NSLog("Fetched Error Category for \(categoryItem.categoryName) ")
        }
    }

}


import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(IICategoryModel)
class IICategoryModel: NSObject
{
    var categoryName: String = ""
    var subCategoryName: String = ""
}
```

I refer this gitHub Library...
    https://github.com/iascchen/SwiftCoreDataSimpleDemo

[image]

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: The error is probably elsewhere, when you create an instance of `IICategoryDAO`.  You must use the designated initialiser, `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`, not just a simple `init`.  My guess is you have declared a variable like this: `var myObject = IICategoryDAO()`, which creates an instance using the standard `init`.

Comment: ok so what is the alternative for that

Comment: @pritam Can you post the code where you declare the IICategoryDAO variable / create the instance?

Comment: var categoryDAO = IICategoryDAO()

Comment: @pritam Sorry, can you edit your post to include more of the code where you declare and use `categoryDAO`?  The best solution depends on how that code works.

Comment: @pritam Looking more closely, I think you are subclassing the wrong classes:  `IICategoryDAO` should subclass `NSObject`, and `IICategoryModel` should subclass `NSManagedObject`.